# Xarmarin Studio C# Trying to start new activity from button press

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to start a new activity in my C# app using a button from the Main.axml file, and I get the following error :

> The name "button" does not exist in current context

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/NpdKiQV5.

Comment: Please post your code in a code snippet in SO instead of pastebin (your snippet is short enough to do so). Also, do not include your question in the title next time. Finally, when you include an error message, copy-paste it, don't rewrite it otherwise it can be less accurate (in your case, it just contains a typo, but sometimes it is worth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means exactly what it says, there is no variable named `button` anywhere in your code.  You need to declare a button variable assign it to a variable in your class.  I assume you are

```
var button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button);
```

I assume you are used to something like Windows Forms where the designer automatically creates the form variables for you.  This is not how Android works.  You have to call `FindViewById` to retrieve references to every control in your view.